# proof $f$ is analytic in open set $D$

Tags: complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, analytic-functions

I'm struggling to prove that $f(z)=\int^{1}_{0}{\frac{1}{1-zt^2}dt}$
is analytic in open set: $D=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}|\left|{z}\right|<1\right\}$  I don't know how to prove that, I though using Morera's theorem but I don't see how.

Comment: Applying Morera's theorem is a good idea. Take a parametrization of the triangle and apply Fubini's theorem (as each integrand for fixed $t$ is analytic itself).

Comment: @nejimban I'm not used to parametrize of the triangle, can I parametrize to the unit circle? also, we didn't learn about Fubini's theorem, what I can do instead?

Comment: You can take any contour, I guess. Do you know the change of variable formula in integrals?

Comment: @nejimban I know I need to change the variable, but I don't sure who, is it $z$ or $t$?

Comment: For this particular case, Morera's theorem isn't necessary. You can directly expand $\frac{1}{1-zt^2}$ as a geometric series, and interchange the series with integral (the Weiertrass M-test gives for each $z\in D$, uniform convergence with respect to $t\in [0,1]$ so the interchange is valid), so you can directly even calculate the Taylor expansion of $f$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

We apply Morera's theorem. We need to show that:

1. $f$ defines a continuous function on $D$;
2. $\oint_{\Delta} f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$ for any triangle $\Delta\subset D$.

*Proof of 1.* This easily follows from the dominated convergence theorem. (We have $$\left\lvert\frac1{1-zt^2}\right\rvert\le\frac{1+|z|}{(1-\Re z)^2}$$ for all $z\in D$ and $t\in[0,1]$.)

*Proof of 2.* Let $\Delta:=[a,b,c]\subset D$  be a triangle. Then
$$
\oint_\Delta f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_{[a,b]}f(z)\,\mathrm dz+\int_{[b,c]}f(z)\,\mathrm dz+\int_{[c,a]}f(z)\,\mathrm dz.$$
We have
\begin{align*}\int_{[a,b]}f(z)\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^1(b-a)f\bigl(a+u(b-a)\bigr)\,\mathrm du\\[.4em]
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1\frac{b-a}{1-\bigl(a+u(b-a)\bigr)t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right)\mathrm du
\\[.4em]
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1\frac{b-a}{1-\bigl(a+u(b-a)\bigr)t^2}\,\mathrm du\right)\mathrm dt&\color{red}{/!\backslash}\\[.4em]
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_{[a,b]}\frac{\mathrm dz}{1-zt^2}\right)\mathrm dt,
\end{align*}
and similarly on $[b,c]$ and $[c,a]$. We deduce that
\begin{align*}
\oint_\Delta f(z)\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^1\left(\int_{[a,b]}\frac{\mathrm dz}{1-zt^2}+\int_{[b,c]}\frac{\mathrm dz}{1-zt^2}+\int_{[c,a]}\frac{\mathrm dz}{1-zt^2}\right)\mathrm dt\\[.4em]
&=\int_0^1\left(\oint_\Delta\frac{\mathrm dz}{1-zt^2}\right)\mathrm dt,
\end{align*}
and each inner integral there is $0$ because $z\mapsto\frac1{1-zt^2}$ is holomorphic on $D$ (for any fixed $t\in[0,1]$).

*$\color{red}{/!\backslash}$ One should justify that one can change the order of integration here.*

Comment: First of all, thank you, can you elaborate more about this step: $\int_{[a,b]}f(z)dz = \int_{0}^{1}(b-a)f(a+u(b-a))du$. also I don't understand proof.1 how easily you got that

Comment: I simply parametrize the segment $[a,b]$ as $u\in[0,1]\mapsto a+u(b-a)$. So $z=a+u(b-a)$, $\mathrm dz=(b-a)\mathrm du$, with $u\in[0,1]$.

Comment: For the inequality in 1., write $\frac1{1-zt^2}=\frac{1-\bar zt^2}{(1-zt^2)(1-\bar zt^2)}$.